# Why do ConcurrentQueue and ConcurrentDictionary have "Try" methods - TryAdd, TryDequeue - instead of Add and Dequeue?

Tags: c#, collections, concurrentdictionary, concurrent-queue

`ConcurrentQueue` has `TryDequeue` method.

`Queue` has just `Dequeue` method.

In `ConcurrentDictionary` there is no `Add` method, but we have `TryAdd` instead.

My question is:

**What is the diffrence between these concurrent collection methods? Why they are diffrent for concurrent collections?**

Comment: since they ensure thread safety access, tryadd may fail if the current thread cant access the dictionary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` it's assumed that you're going to implement your own logic to make sure duplicate keys aren't entered. For example,

```
if(!myDictionary.ContainsKey(key)) myDictionary.Add(key, value);
```

But we use Concurrent collections when we have multiple threads going and it's possible that they could both be trying to modify the dictionary at the same time.

If two threads tried to execute the above code at the same time, it's possible that `myDictionary.ContainsKey(key)` could return false for both threads because they're both checking at the same time and that key hasn't been added yet. Then they both try to add the key, and one fails.

Someone reading that code who doesn't know it's multithreaded could be confused. I checked to make sure that the key wasn't in the dictionary *before* I added it. So how am I getting an exception?

`ConcurrentDictionary.TryAdd` solves that by allowing you to "try" to add the key. If it adds the value it returns `true`. If it doesn't it returns `false`. But what it *won't* do is conflict with another `TryAdd` and throw an exception.

You could do all of that yourself by wrapping the `Dictionary` in a class and putting `lock` statements around it to make sure only one thread at a time makes changes. `ConcurrentDictionary` just does that for you and does it really well. You don't have to see all the details of how it's working - you just use it knowing that multithreading has been accounted for.

Here's a detail to look for when using a class in a multithreaded application. If you go to the documentation for [ConcurrentDictionary Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) and scroll to the bottom you'll see this:

> **Thread Safety**
>   *All public and protected members* of
>   ConcurrentDictionary are thread-safe and *may be used*
>   *concurrently from multiple threads*. However, members accessed through
>   one of the interfaces the ConcurrentDictionary
>   implements, including extension methods, are not guaranteed to be
>   thread safe and may need to be synchronized by the caller.

In other words, multiple threads can safely read and modify the collection.

Under [Dictionary Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll see this:

> **Thread Safety**
>   A Dictionary can support multiple
>   *readers* concurrently, *as long as the collection is not modified*. Even
>   so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a
>   thread-safe procedure. *In the rare case where an enumeration contends*
>   *with write accesses, the collection must be locked during the entire*
>   *enumeration*. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple
>   threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own
>   synchronization.

Multiple threads can read keys, but if multiple threads are going to *write* then you need to somehow `lock` the dictionary to make sure only one thread at a time tries to update.

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` exposes a `Keys` collection and `Values` collection so you can enumerate the keys and values, but it warns you not to try doing that if another thread is going to be modifying the dictionary. You can't enumerate something while items are being added or removed. If you need to iterate through the keys or values then you have to lock the dictionary to prevent updates during that iteration.

`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` assumes that there will be multiple threads reading and writing, so it doesn't even expose key or value collections for you to enumerate.

Answer (score 4):

Semantics is different.

Failing of `Queue.Dequeue` usually indicates a problem with internal application logic, so throwing exceptions is good in such cases.

However failing of [`ConcurrentQueue.TryDeque`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287208(v=vs.110).aspx) is something which might be expected in the regular flow, so avoiding exception and returning a `Boolean` is a reasonable way to handle it.

> `ConcurrentQueue<T>` handles all synchronization internally. If two threads call `TryDequeue` at precisely the same moment, neither operation is blocked. When a conflict is detected between two threads, one thread has to try again to retrieve the next element, and the synchronization is handled internally.

(It is common practice in .NET framework to have `Try...` functions which return Boolean results instead of throwing, see e.g. `TryParse` methods.)

Answer (score 4):

The reason these methods are given a `Try` semantics is that by design, there is no way to reliably tell that `Dequeue` or `Add` operations are going to succeed.

When the queue is not concurrent, you could check if there's anything to dequeue before calling `Dequeue` method. Similarly, you can check if the key in a non-concurrent `Dictionary` is present or not. You cannot do the same to concurrent classes, because someone may dequeue your item after you checked for it to be there, but before you get to actually dequeue it. In other words, `Try` operations let you check the precondition and perform the operation *atomically*.

An alternative approach would be letting you dequeue or add anyway, and throw an exception when the operation fails, in the way the non-concurrent implementations do. The drawback to this approach is that these exceptional situations in non-concurrent classes are entirely expected in concurrent classes, so using exception handling for them would be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

As these collections are designed to be used concurrently, you can't rely on checking pre-conditions in a sequential manner, you need an atomic operation.

Taking the dictionary as an example, ordinarily you'd be able to write code like this:

```
if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
{
    dictionary.Add(key, value);
}
```

In a situation where multiple threads are using the same dictionary, it would be perfectly possible for another thread to have inserted a value with the same key in between you checking `ContainsKey` and calling `Add`.

`TryAdd` solves this as it will either succeed or fail depending on whether the key exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/dd287208(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Tries to remove and return the object at the beginning of the
>   concurrent queue.

Returns

> true if an element was removed and returned from the beginning of the
>   ConcurrentQueue successfully; otherwise, false.

So if you can remove `TryDequeue` just reomove and return it, if can't returns false and you know to try again when queeue is free.